# jQuery: Select newly created element in click on function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a `data-attribute` from my newly created element. I am using the following code to list for new elements:

```
$('.sortable').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.data('data-file'));
});
```

However the `console.log()` is throwing an error, is it possible to retrieve data attributes from newly created elements? I am trying to pass an ID of the file that was added to the UI.

Comment: `$(this).data('file')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `data-` prefix is not required

```
 console.log(e.data('file'));
```

Comment: $(e.target).data('file')